# Dictionary Keys based on list elements and list values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-2.7

I am scanning through a document making a list of each line read in.

I'm saving this to a list called

```
testList = []
```

When I'm done populating this list I want to set it as a value into a dictionary whose key is based on the element of another list.
The idea is it should look something like this:

```
testList = ['InformationA', 'InformationB', 'Lastinfo']
patent_offices = ['European Office', 'Japan Office']
dict_offices[patent_offices[0]] = testList
```

or

```
dict_offices = {'European Office' : ['InformationA', 'InformationB', 'Lastinfo'],
'Japan Office' : ['Other list infoA', 'more infoB']}
```

I want to later type `dict_offices['European Office']` and get the list printed.

But because I'm collecting this dynamically as I read through a document I erase and reuse  `testList`. What I've seen is after it is cleared it is also cleared in the dictionary's link.

How do I create the dictionary so it is saved so that I can reuse testList every loop through?

Here is my code:

```
patent_offices = []
dict_offices = {}
office_index = 0
testList = []

# --- other conditional code not shown

if (not patent_match and start_recording):
                if ( not re.search(r'[=]+', bString)): #Ignore ====== string

                        printString = fontsString.encode('ascii', 'ignore')   
                        testList.append(printString)                         


    elif (not start_recording and patent_match):

                dict_offices[patent_offices[office_index]] = testList
                start_recording = True
                office_index += 1
                testList[:] = []
```

This dictionary is correctly updated and looks exactly like I want it to until I call the

```
testList[:] = []
```

line. This the dictionary goes blank just like `testList`. I understand that the dictionary is linked to this but I don't know how to not have this happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lists are mutable; multiple references to the same list will see all the changes you make to it. `testList[:] = []` means: replace every *index in this list* with an empty list. Because you reference the same list in different places (including in the dictionary values), you see the change reflected everywhere.

Instead, just point `testList` to a *new* empty list instead:

```
testList = []
```

The empty slice assignment syntax you used should only be used if you want to clear the *contents* of a list, not when you simply want to create a new empty list.

```
>>> foo = []
>>> bar = foo
>>> foo.append(1)
>>> bar
[1]
>>> foo is bar
True
>>> foo[:] = []
>>> bar
[]
>>> foo = ['new', 'list']
>>> bar
[]
>>> foo is bar
False
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just needed these updates on proper use, etc.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to do a deepcopy, [see copy.html](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)

```
dict_offices[patent_offices[office_index]] = copy.deepcopy(testList)
```

example:

```
l = [1,2,3]
b = l
del l[:]
print(b)
 ---> []

l = [1,2,3]
b = copy.deepcopy(l)
l = []
print (b)
  ---> [1,2,3]
```